# XAML with dynamic margin height

Tags: xaml, windows-8

I'm looking for something like a dynamic margin or flexible space in XAML but couldn't find something.

This XAML:

```
        <HubSection VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Products>" Foreground="#FF464646" FontSize="36" Margin="0,-50,0,0"></TextBlock>
                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Button Background="#FF00AEFF" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button1"></Button>
                        <Button Background="#FFFF8000" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button2"></Button>
                        <Button Background="#FFDE0101" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button3"></Button>
                        <Button Background="#FF6300DA" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button4"></Button>
                        <Button Background="#FF973E00" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button5"></Button>
                        <Button Background="#FF00AA1F" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button6"></Button>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

Gives me:

[image]

But the buttons should have margins between them to fill the space according to the available screen height.

Something like this:

[image]

Is there something like a dynamic margin height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it grid and it will work like a charm.

```
   <HubSection VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Yellow">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="Products>" Foreground="#FF464646" FontSize="36" Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Pink" Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                        <Button Background="#FF00AA1F" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button6" Grid.Row="6"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <Button Background="#FF00AEFF" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button1" ></Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                        <Button Background="#FFFF8000" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button2" Grid.Row="2"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
                        <Button Background="#FFDE0101" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button3" Grid.Row="3"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="4">
                        <Button Background="#FF6300DA" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button4" Grid.Row="4"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                        <Button Background="#FF973E00" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button5" Grid.Row="5"></Button>
                    </Grid>

                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HubSection>
```

This will solve your problem. I have added colors just that you know which grid is using which space.

Comment: Good solution. But I don't think that you need all the Grids around the buttons. Just apply Grid.Row directly to the buttons.

Comment: It will work . Grid gives you more control that's why used it.

Comment: Indeed. Too bad that the `UniformGrid` is not available in WinRT, it would be perfect for this job.

Comment: Nice solution - and the UI stays in the UI I like that. Thanks a lot Rohit!

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to hardcode the XAML and keep the XAML clean, be able to add items, I have created the SpaceChildrenBehavior

```
<Grid  Background="AliceBlue" >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:SpaceChildrenBehavior/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Background="#FF00AEFF" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button1"></Button>
            <Button Background="#FFFF8000" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button2"></Button>
            <Button Background="#FFDE0101" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button3"></Button>
            <Button Background="#FF6300DA" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button4"></Button>
            <Button Background="#FF973E00" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button5"></Button>
            <Button Background="#FF00AA1F" Width="260" Height="60" Content="Button6"></Button>
        </Grid>
```

This is the XAML (really clean)

and the behaviour

```
public class SpaceChildrenBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{
    public DependencyObject AssociatedObject { get; private set; }

    public Grid AssociatedGrid;
    EventHandler<object> layoutupdated= null;
    public void Attach(DependencyObject associatedObject)
    {
        AssociatedObject = associatedObject;

        AssociatedGrid = associatedObject as Grid;

        layoutupdated = async (s, e) =>
        {
            if (AssociatedGrid.ActualHeight > 0)
            {
                AssociatedGrid.LayoutUpdated -= layoutupdated;
                await Task.Delay(100);
                AssociatedGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
                int i = -1;

                foreach (var child in AssociatedGrid.Children)
                {
                    AssociatedGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
                    { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
                    Grid.SetRow(child as FrameworkElement, ++i);
                }
                AssociatedGrid.LayoutUpdated += layoutupdated;
            }

        };
        AssociatedGrid.LayoutUpdated += layoutupdated;

    }

    public void Detach()
    {
        AssociatedGrid.LayoutUpdated -= layoutupdated;
    }
}
```

Now is dynamic, you can add more items and it will adapt the grid rows